# I have a plugin where in I have to change the title of the page dynamically by sending parameter to the_title filter

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I am using shortcode and in that I want to change the title by setting the value from the database using custom tables.I have tried using the_title filter as follows

```
add_filter('the_title','set_page_title', 10, 2);
function set_page_title($title, $id){
   if(in_the_loop()) {


         return 'sdfdsfdsf';
   }
   return $title;
}
```

But my problem is I want to change this only on a specific page not all page.

This is my shortcode callback function

```
function bmg_company_detail_shortcode($args, $content) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'bmg_company';
    $company_id = $_GET['id'];
    $output = '';

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id,maincategoryid,name,website,yearfounded,supportpageurl,contactpage,country,about, isactive,contact_name,contact_email,contact_phone,support_phone,open_times,support_email, username, password  from $table_name where id=%s", $company_id));



  if($result) {
      foreach($result as $row) {
           set_page_title('',$row->name);
          $output = '
            <h3 class="bmg-company-title">'. $row->name .'</h3>

          ';
      }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

I want to send the parameter to the function set_page_title but that doesn't work. I want this to happen only on page called company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_page()` function to only change it on a certain page. I'm assuming the slug of your company page is in fact `company`

```
add_filter( 'the_title','wpse_277956_the_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse_277956_the_title( $title, $id ){
   if( in_the_loop() && is_page( 'company' ) ) {    
         return bmg_company_detail_shortcode( false, false );
   }
   return $title;
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning shortcode callback function in the_title callback function? Your answer solved my problem partially. Now i want to set a data to the_title callback function. I want to set from database in shortcode function

Answer (score 0):

Getting the id from URL of the page got me fixed.

```
add_filter('the_title','set_page_title', 10, 2);
function set_page_title($title, $id){
   if(in_the_loop() && is_page( 'company' )) {
       $cid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';  
       if($cid != '') {
            return get_company_name($cid);
       } else {
            return $title;   
       }
   }
   return $title;
}
```